# Pattern not getting matched in regex

Tags: java, regex, split, regex-negation

I would like to match the comma's which are only outside the double quotes

I have written a regex as `(?!(\"){1}(^\")*(\"){1})(,)`

But this is not working!!! 
Can anyone please let me know the problem with this regex and correct it

The example is as follows :
If the string is `abc,def,"ghi,jkl,mno",pqr,stu,"wxy"`
If we do split on `,` by using regex then output should be should be as follows

```
abc
def
ghi,jkl,mno
pqr
stu
wxy
```

Comment: Oh, this is not that difficult as you wrote. Just match all double quoted substrings and capture them, use an alternation operator `|` and add a `,` as a separate branch. Or vice versa. You may then replace the comma with some character you won't be using and split with it.

Comment: Looks like he's doing a CSV field parsing.

Comment: I need to split the string with comma's which are outside the double quotes as shown in example

Comment: If it is CSV, use a CSV parser.

Comment: I need to do this using split method of java

Comment: Might be worth testing it out on this site http://regexr.com/ I check all my regex expressions here